# Labels cutted if graphic have not space

Tags: c#, winforms

I have bar chart where I set labels at top of each bar like:

```
graphTasksCompleted.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
graphTasksCompleted.Series[item.TaskName].SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = false;
graphTasksCompleted.Series[item.TaskName].LabelAngle = -90;
graphTasksCompleted.Series[item.TaskName].Label = item.TaskName;
graphTasksCompleted.Series[item.TaskName].LabelBackColor = Color.Black;
graphTasksCompleted.Series[item.TaskName].LabelForeColor = Color.White;
```

Problem is somethimes label can disappear if "Y" value is at the top of graphic area:
[image]

As you can see my labels are cutted, there is some trick to fix this? Regards

Comment: What would you consider a "fix" to be?  Overlapping the bar?  Lowering the font size?  Moving the label to another position?  You need to tell us what you think should happen, as there is no magic fix to this sort of thing.

Comment: I mean how can I get max "Y" amount of chart created and for example if max Y is 60 and my bar have 50 just  fix it changing labelAngle from -90 to 90, but the question is, how can I get max "Y" position when graphic is creating @DonBoitnott